# How can Plack applications log to multiple loggers?

Tags: perl, logging, plack, psgi

Plack Middleware is very useful, for instance to configure logging targets independent of the application. But I have not found a method to use multiple loggers at the same time:

```
my $app = MyApp->new();

builder {
  enable 'ConsoleLogger'; # show in Client's console
  enable 'SimpleLogger';  # show on STDERR
  $app;
}
```

With this configuration 'SimpleLogger' is muted by 'ConsoleLogger', but I want to log by both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this writing you can't. I've been thinking about having a new logger middleware that acts as a sort of proxy, to dispatch logging to multiple middleware, but haven't got any tuit to write one.

Comment: Ok - that's not a positive answer, but at least I do not need to waste my time searching for a non-existing solution. A Proxy would be great but it's not on top of my priorities.